# Winforms DevExpress Xtragrid conditional formatting - using just part of functionality

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

Is it possible to enable just part of Conditional Formatting functionality to user? Looks like only "Highlight Cell Rules" submenu options are fast enough to handle grid with continuous updates.

Is it possible to limit "Conditional Formatting" to just "Highlight Cell Rules" submenu? If not - how can I call same dialog from custom menu?

Where can I find standard data bar rendering functionality to display same cell style from my custom code?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GridView.PopupMenuShowing`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_PopupMenuShowingtopic) event to customize popup menu before it is displayed. Check the [`PopupMenuShowingEventArgs.MenuType`](http://PopupMenuShowingEventArgs.MenuType%20Property) property to get the column menu and use [`PopupMenuShowingEventArgs.Menu`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridPopupMenuShowingEventArgs_Menutopic) property to get the `GridViewMenu` object and its `GridViewMenu.Items` property.
Here is example:

```
private void gridView1_PopupMenuShowing(object sender, PopupMenuShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.MenuType != GridMenuType.Column)
        return;

    DXMenuItem menuItem = null;

    foreach (DXMenuItem item in e.Menu.Items)
        if (item.Tag.Equals(GridStringId.MenuColumnConditionalFormatting))
        {
            item.Visible = false;

            menuItem = ((DXSubMenuItem)item).Items[0];

            break;
        }

    menuItem.BeginGroup = true;

    if (menuItem != null)
        e.Menu.Items.Add(menuItem);
}
```

Comment: Cool :). Do you happen to know if I can call functionality from those menus from my custom code? Or how to apply cell styles that that functionality would have applied? Those bars look good, and I hope I would not have to reimplement same thing in CustomDrawColumn.

Comment: @PiotrR You can apply all of this formatting conditions in your code. Take a look at [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument17691).

Comment: I need to avoid using built in GridFormatRules, because they are to slow when data is constantly changing. I want to run my own values in my code and just make cells look same as in built in conditional formatting, but with my values. Other thing that would be useful is being able to call standard dialog, get values that user provided, and being able to use them in my custom code. Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: @PiotrR You can use `GridView.RowStyle` event and `GridView.RowCellStyle` event. Here is [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758).

Comment: How can reuse style conditional formatting is using? What is property name?

Comment: @PiotrR There are no such property in `GridView`. You should implement all of this by yourself.